# Azure Get Authorization Bearer Token API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm just wondering in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list 
[image]
there's a "try it" button once you click it, it will list all your tenant or directory.
[image]
then once you select any of the directory it will give you a bearer token.
[image].

The question is, is there's a way to get a bearer token thru API? Or get a bearer token that depends on the selected tenant? Thanks!

By the return token of that site, im passing it thru this api https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts to get all my organization base on the selected tenant.

Comment: What kind of app are you building? How you acquire tokens depends on that.

Comment: Im just wondering of there's an way or api that will give me that bearer token. I'm working with Azure Web API.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to work with the command in PowerShell, the [Get-AzAccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azaccesstoken) cmdlet can fetch a token for you.

I tested the following script in PowerShell on Azure Cloud Shell:

```
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl 'https://management.azure.com').Token
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer $token")

$url = "https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01"

# Send the request
Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method 'Get' -Headers $headers
```

Comment: This is awesome snippet - the managed identity access token works with Azure DevOps resources like downloading universal packages from Azure Artifacts or even downloading files from Azure Git repos!

Comment: working great, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the access token (Bearer) via below API. Please refer the link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Normally if you need to access any azure resource, then you have to create AAD app in that tenant in order to get the token. But your case, you have to get all Tenant details via REST api. So You can create the AAD app on of your tenant.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try this 1st. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: were having an error called incorrect username or password, but were 100% sure that we type the correct password.

Comment: Are you receiving this error ? If so your Ad admin should grant the permission for the AAD application.                                                                                           ("The credentials were incorrect or the client doesn't have consent for the requested scopes" )

Comment: This is my error now. AADSTS50053: You've tried to sign in too many times with an incorrect user ID or password.

Comment: this is what I did on granting credential .Azure Active Directory > App Registration >(Click your App) > Settings > Required permissions > Grant permissions.

Comment: I've check all the permision listed on my API.

Comment: according that message, it looks like your credentials got locked. Can you please recheck ? I have tried the same doc and it is worked fine for me.

Comment: My colleague also tried it and return with an incorrect username password, we even put an unknown account and we got (AADSTS50034: The user account does not exist in the directory). On the settings > Required permissions I put add all the permisions like (Windows Azure Service Management API, Office 365 Management APIs, Microsoft Graph, Azure DevOps, Windows Azure Active Directory) and enable all access inside one of those permision.

Comment: Okay. Where did you crate the AAD APP. I mean inside which tenant ? I think that I need more info about this case, If you wish please contact me on Linkedin, https://www.linkedin.com/in/issak-mohamed-infaaz-42473b99